# What's the point of using Future without multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, future, completable-future

I've inherited some code and there is nobody of the original developers left. The code uses heavily `CompletableFuture`, and it's the first time I use it, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. As I understand it, a `(Completable)Future` is typically used with some multithreading mechanism that will allow us to do some other thing while a time consuming task is executing, and then simply fetch its result via the Future. As in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

```
interface ArchiveSearcher { String search(String target); }
class App {
    ExecutorService executor = ...
    ArchiveSearcher searcher = ...
    void showSearch(final String target) throws InterruptedException {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            return searcher.search(target);
        }});
        displayOtherThings(); // do other things while searching
        try {
            displayText(future.get()); // use future
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) { cleanup(); return; }
    }
}
```

However, in this application that I've inherited, the following pattern that doesn't use any multithreading appears a bunch of times:

```
public Object serve(Object input) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Object> result = delegate1(input);
    return result.get();
}

private CompletableFuture<Object> delegate1(Object input) {
    // Do things
    return delegate2(input);
}

private CompletableFuture<Object> delegate2(Object input) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Object());
}
```

To me, this is equivalent to:

```
public Object serve(Object input) {
    Object result = delegate1(input);
    return result;
}

private Object delegate1(Object input) {
    // Do things
    return delegate2(input);
}

private Object delegate2(Object input) {
    return new Object();
}
```

Of course the code is much more complex, and returns `exceptionallyCompletedFuture` in case of error, but there are is `Callable`, no `Runnable`, no `Executor`, no `supplyAsync()` no sign of multithreading. What am I missing? What's the point of using a `Future` in a singled-threaded context?

Comment: Is there an UI feamework involved? Lots get slow, if the main thread calculates things.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach No, there isn't. But what if there was? What do you mean by "main thread"? My point is that, to my understanding, with the above approach everything is "main thread".

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, but I've seen a lot of Android questions in which "main thread" seems to mean something different from what I usually think of as the main thread.  Something more like Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Event dispatcher thread is what I meant.

Comment: Are you sure there is no object proxying or bytecode weaving involved, that could actually make some method calls run on a different thread? For example Spring has the `@Async` annotation that tells to run a method in a configured thread pool, while immediately returning a linked but uncompleted `@CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 2):

Futures are critical for situations where there is asynchronous programming.  One of the biggest advantages of asynchronous programming is it allows you to write very efficient code with a single thread.

Furthermore, futures tend to be an all-or-nothing proposition.  If you want to write asynchronous code you have to do so from top to bottom, even if not every method does something asynchronous.

For example, consider you want to write a single threaded HTTP server like [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [express](https://expressjs.com/).  The top level of your server (very liberal pseudocode here) might look something like:

```
while (true) {
  if (serverSocket.ready()) {
    connection = serverSocket.accept();
    futures.add(server.serve(connection));
  }
  for (Future future : futures) {
    if (future.isDone()) {
      Object result = future.get();
      sendResult(result);
    }
  }
  //Some kind of select-style wait here
}
```

There is only one thread but any time an operation happens that would normally require a wait (reading from database, file, reading in the request, etc.) it uses futures and doesn't block the one thread so you have a highly performant single threaded HTTP server.

Now, imagine what would happen if the highest level of your application was like the above and at some point some request at a very low level had to read something from a file.  That file read would generate a future.  If all of your middle layers in between didn't handle futures then you would have to block and it would defeat the purpose.  This is why I say futures tend to be all-or-nothing.

So my guess is either:

1. Your friend does something asynchronous currently and you haven't caught it yet (does he ever read from a file or database or anything?  If so, is he blocking?).
2. He was planning on someday doing something asynchronous and wanted to plan for it.
3. He spent a lot of time in other asynchronous frameworks and grew to like the style even if he isn't using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for now there is no multithreading used in that code. Looks like there was an intention to write single-threaded code in such a way that if developer later decides to use multithreading then only

```
delegate2()
```

method should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

ExecutorService implementations typically manage threads. I've used the ThreadPoolExecutor, which does exactly that. You commented out which ExecutorService your code uses.

Comment: The code snippet that uses an `ExecutorService` is a counterexample--It's an example of something that the OP _does_ understand.  The actual question is about the call to `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(...)` in the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The main point of asynchronous code is to defer the continuation code.

The most common scenario is I/O, where instead of waiting for an operation to finish, you say "do your thing and notify me when you're finished", or more commonly, "do your thing and do this when you're finished".

This doesn't imply threads at all.  Reading from any device, be it a network card or a hard drive, usually has some sort of signal or interrupt sent from the device to the CPU.  You could use the CPU in the meantime.  The "notify me" is more common in lower-level code, where you implement a dispatching loop or scheduler; the "do this" is more common in higher-level code, where you use an established library or framework that dispatches and/or schedules for you.

Less common scenarios include deferring execution without blocking a thread (think of a timer versus `Thread.sleep()`) and splitting work.  Actually, splitting work is very common with multiple threads, where you can improve performance with a bit of overhead, but not so much with a single thread, where the overhead is just, well, overhead.

---

The code you provide as an example that just builds completed `CompletableFuture`s, whether successfully or exceptionally, is a part of the overhead of asynchronous code that isn't really asynchronous.  That is, you must still follow a defined async style, which in this case requires a small amount of memory allocation for results, even if you can provide results immediately.

This may become noticeable on thousands of calls per second, or hundreds of calls per second per thread with dozens of threads.

Sometimes, you can optimize by having predefined completed futures for e.g. `null`, `0`, `1`, `-1`, an empty array/list/stream, or any other very common or even fixed result you may have specifically in your domain.  A similar approach is to cache a wrapping future, not just the result, while the result remains the same.  But I suggest you first profile before going this way, you may end up optimizing prematurely something that most probably is not a bottleneck.